# Attempting to change text of label in accordion row via item in accordion detail

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have an accordion that uses the datasource `Competency`, which stores a list of core competencies for their employees and the related metadata (such as a description). Inside the Accordion's detail, I have a panel that uses the `Comment` datasource. A user can then enter a comment that will get related to the `Competency` datasources with some unrelated logic.

Right now, I have an empty checkbox (check_box_outline_blank) in the Accordion Row. When a user enters text, I want the checkbox to have a check (i.e. change the value from `check_box_outline_blank` to `check_box`) The problem is that I'm not able to figure out a way to select the checkbox.

Selecting with `widget.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.children.DetailAccordionRow.children.CompletionIcon.text = "check_box";` results in the error

```
 Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
at CheckinSubmit.RootPanel.FormPanel.AccordionPanel.DetailAccordion.DetailAccordionDetail.AccordionDetialPanel.CommentFormPanel.CreateCommentForm.CreateCommentFormBody.Field.onValueEdit:1:78
```

Selecting with `app.pages.CheckinSubmit.children.RootPanel.children.FormPanel.children.AccordionPanel.children.DetailAccordion.children.DetailAccordionRow.children.CompletionIcon.text = "check_box";`

Throws the error:

```
Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
at CheckinSubmit.RootPanel.FormPanel.AccordionPanel.DetailAccordion.DetailAccordionDetail.AccordionDetialPanel.CommentFormPanel.CreateCommentForm.CreateCommentFormBody.Panel3.onValueEdit:1:140
```

Both commands were put into the Submit button's onValueEdit trigger.

I've been using AppMaker's autosugguestions to generate both of these commands. I'm not sure how else to select this item. Here's a screenshot with the UI and outline:
[image: screenshot of project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use binding? It seems, that you are adding Comments to the Competency, so maybe this binding for the label's text will work?

```
@datasource.item.Comments.length > 0 ? 'check_box' : 'check_box_outline_blank'
```

> when a user enters text, I want the checkbox to have a check

if you want exactly this behavior, and you have properly configured bindings, then you can bind label's text to something similar to this:

```
@datasource.relations.Comments.modes.create.item.Comment !== null ?
    'check_box' : 'check_box_outline_blank'
```

**Note** that bindings will be reevaluated on focus loss of the Comment input (but there is a workaround for that).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pavel. The second line worked great!  
Also, it doesn't "un-check" if I delete the data as it's supposed to if the comment text area is set to Required, but I'm sure I can find a workaround for that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: 'delete the data' - you mean when you use backspace/delete button do delete text inside the comment textbox?

Comment: Yes... `required` flag is not your friend in this situation )) You can try to uncheck it and play with `onValidate` event handler of the text input. You can trigger `onValidate` in `onClick` handler of the Submit button with this snippet `widget.parent.parent.validate()` if you are using default AM form layout.